# How to find the center of a circle, given a point on the circumference of the circle, radius and arc length?

Tags: geometry, circles

As shown in the figure below, I know:

- a point $(x_1, y_1)$ on a circle
- the length of an arc (of the same circle) starting at $(x_1, y_1)$
- the angle $\theta$ subtended by this arc at the center of the circle
- the radius $R$ of the circle

How can I find:

1. the coordinates of the center of the circle?
2. $(x_2, y_2)$?

[image]

Comment: How is the arc length relevant?

Comment: I found Arc Length using the formula (Theta / Radius).

Comment: It is not directly relevant but it is one of the parameter which is available. If needed in any formula

Comment: Is something else known about the arc whose only arc length is given? Otherwise the position of the centre can't be determined uniquely.

Comment: The center of the circle can be anywhere on the perimeter of a circle with its center at $(x_1,x_2)$ and radius $R$.

Comment: The arc is starting from the point whose coordinates are known and the angle between the two endpoints of the arc is also known but only one endpoint is known

Comment: @Seyed Your comment has an error in the coordinates, but aside from this, it is essentially an answer. I have turned it into an [actual answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4056251/843797), with credit to you.

Comment: @Brian Drake, You are right, sorry it was a typo, I meant $(x_1, y_1)$. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 1):

**There are infinitely many possible answers.**

The figure shows which direction $(x_1, y_1)$ and $(x_2, y_2)$ are, relevant to the centre. However, the text does not reference this information, so it is not clear whether we can rely on it.

Assuming we cannot rely on this information, [Seyed’s comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4056179/how-to-find-the-center-of-a-circle-given-a-point-on-the-circumference-of-the-ci#comment8378902_4056179) applies (with a slight correction):

> The center of the circle can be anywhere on the perimeter of a circle with its center at $(x_1, y_1)$ and radius $R$.

Comment: So Mathematically there is no such formula to find the endpoint of an arc given another endpoint, radius, angle between endpoints of the arc and arc length without Center Coordinates?

Comment: The information is enough to determine the “shape and size” of the arc, if you want to put it that way, but it is not enough to determine the *direction* of the arc. (Imagine you rotated your diagram, the translated it so that $(x_1, y_1)$ was in the same place was it was initially. The radius, angle and arc length would stay the same, but the quantities you are looking for would change.)

Comment: An upvote from me.

Answer (score 0):

- among radius, arc length and subtended angle, one parameter can be deduced from the others;
- as you don't know the coordinates of the point $p_2$, the information about this point cannot be exploited !
- a circle of radius $r$ and passing through $p_1$ has its center somewhere on the circle of radius $r$ centered at $p_1$.

This is all you can say.

Comment: What are $p_1$ and $p_2$?

Comment: @BrianDrake p1 is the point which is known (x1,y1) and p2 is the point which we need to find (x2,y2) according to the figure

Comment: @NityaShukla This information should have been included in the answer.